# Tkinter: how to colorize the outline of a canvas rectangle?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I draw a rectangle on a Canvas:

```
 canvas = Canvas(parent,  cursor="cross")   
 rect = canvas.create_rectangle(20,20, 1, 1, fill="")
```

I only want to draw the border, leaving the interior transparent (that is why I set `fill=""` as mentioned [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_rectangle-method)).

**My problem:**

I want the rectangle to have a red border. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, the interior of a rectangle is empty, and you can also get this
behavior with `fill=''` rather than just leaving it out.

If you want the rectangle outlined, just add a keyword argument named `outline` to the `create_rectangle()` call:

```
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(20,20, 1, 1, outline='red')
```

You can also control the width of the border by also adding a `width=xxx` keyword argument to the call. The default width is 1 pixel.

Comment: Thank you very much (I needed to enhance the width too, I forgot to mention it but you did : )

Answer (score 2):

From the [page you linked](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_rectangle-method):

> *outline*=
> Outline color. Default is “black”.

Comment: thank you, i upvoted, but i accepted the earliest answer

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, but please don't accept an answer because it is the earliest, accept the answer that is [most helpful to you, personally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/276063). If martineau's answer fits that, you are completely right to accept his answer and not mine, no further justification needed. And for the record, I was 1 minute and 20 seconds earlier than martineau ;)